# Error trying to access Amazon Redshift external table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, avro, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have avro files in S3 which I want to be able to query via Redshift. Have used external tables with success in the past but only in parquet/JSON format so wondering whether I'm missing something with the data being in avro format maybe.

I set up a glue crawler to get hold of the schema of the files and that has worked fine. I can access the data in Athena. I've also set up an external schema in Redshift and can see the new external table exists when I query SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES. However, when I come to query the new table I get the following error:

> [XX000][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: Invalid
>   DataCatalog response for external table
>   "spectrum_google_analytics"."man": Cannot deserialize Table. Error:

I don't know why this would work for athena but not spectrum. Hoping you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The same issue happened to be as well when I was trying to use aws-cdk for deploying resources. Turns out having no parameters in properties of Glue Table will cause this weird behaviour (https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7826), add some property like classification=Parquet/JSON and try again, worked for me.

[image]